# Mostrar un div luego de usar el Validate para hacer Submit

Tags: jquery, formularios

tengo la siguiente situacion

Tengo un formulario el cual valido por medio de validate con sus rules, messages y funciona bien, lo que necesito es que una vez que todo este bien me muestre un div en donde he hecho varios calculos y esta con display none desde el principio, lo que no he logrado es que me muestre el div oculto el cual tengo en submitHandler, ese es el codigo

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form2").validate({
    event: "blur",rules: {
        'mat_directos': {required: true, number: true},
        'mat_obras_directos': "required",
        'cantidad': "required",
        'CIF': "required"},
    messages: {
        'mat_directos': "Favor Digitar MAD",
        'mat_obras_directos': "Favor Digitar MOD",
        'cantidad': "Digite la Cantidad",
        'CIF': "Favor seleccione una opción"},      
    submitHandler: function(form){                  
        /* LA siguiente linea muestra el div*/
        $( "#element" ).show( "slow" );         
        form.submit();
     }
});
```

El Div que deseo mostrar lo tengo identificado con un ID element

De antemano gracias por la ayuda

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema radica en que quieres mostrar un div y justo después hacer el submit y no alcanzas a ver el div mostrado con show ya que la petición es enviada antes.

Veo una solución que puedes modificar a tu conveniencia

Código HTML (Incluir JQuery):

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<div id="message">
    <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<form id="target" action="#">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Hello there" name="my_text">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Código Javascript:

```
// find elements
var banner = $("#message")

// handle click and add class
$("#target").validate({
    event: "blur",
    rules: {
        'my_text': {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        'my_text': "Introduca texto"
    },      
    submitHandler: function(form){                  
        /* LA siguiente linea muestra el div*/
        $( "#message" ).show( "slow" );
        setTimeout(function() {
            form.submit();
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/josueguol/buyo28hz/

En este código puse un setTimeout que permite ver durante 5 segundos el div antes de ser enviada la solicitud.

Tú, en vez de usar el setTimeout podrías agregar alguna validación de si los datos son correctos y con un if controlar el .submit()

=============

## ACTUALIZACIÓN

Hola Joe, lo que necesitas entonces no es hacer un form.submit(). Básicamente es hacer un request, enviar los datos por post para que sean procesados por un servicio que te devuelve los datos y pintarlos en ese div. Mira aquí te dejo algo similar:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Cálculos...</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <style>
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  display: none
}

label {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="message">
            <h3>Resultado:</h3>
            <p>
                A x B = <span id="resultado"></span>
            </p>
        </div>

        <form id="target" action="#">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Introduce un número A" name="num_a">
            <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Introduce un número B" name="num_b">
            <input type="submit" value="Go">
        </form>  
        <script>
            // find elements
            var banner = $("#message")

            // handle click and add class
            $("#target").validate({
                event: "blur",
                rules: {
                    'num_a': {
                        required: true,
                        number: true
                    }, 
                    'num_b': {
                        required: true,
                        number: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    'num_a': "Introduce un número",
                    'num_b': "Introduce un número"
                },      
                submitHandler: function(form){                  

                    $.post(
                        'http://localhost/calculo.php',  // url del servicio
                        $('form').serialize(),
                        function(data, status, xhr) {
                            $( "#resultado" ).html(data.resultado);

                            /* La siguiente linea muestra el div*/
                            $( "#message" ).show( "slow" );
                        },
                        'json'
                    );
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y aquí abajo te dejo el servicio que lo hice en php (calculo.php):

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$num_a = $_POST['num_a'];
$num_b = $_POST['num_b'];

$data["resultado"] = $num_a * $num_b;

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: Hola @Josue Guol gracias por tu respuesta, la verdad esta muy bueno... el punto es que el div que tengo oculto necesito que se vea porque ahi es donde muestro la informacion de los calculos realiazados.

Comment: Hola @Josue Guol gracias por tu respuesta, me sirvio excelente... ahora me permite verificar todos los campos que necesito.... lo que no puedo en enviar en formulario... osea al darle submit se queda ahi... no se si en el codigo que me enviaste le falta algo o hay que agragar algo que psermita enviarlo, tu que crees que pueda ser ? Gracias
'código'
if(isset($_POST["guardarorden"])) {
   echo "Hola Miundo";
   Guardar_Orden($num_order);
  }
'código'

Comment: Recuerda que cambiamos el método de envío, antes era **submit()**: que lo que hace es colectar información y la envía a otro lado y forzosamente la página es recargada.

Ahora el método es por **POST**: que lo que hace es, sin recargar la página, colectar la información, hace un _request_ en segundo plano a un servicio que procesa esa información, al recibir la respuesta de ese procesamiento continua estando en la misma página.

Si deseas hacer algo más después usa:
`.done(function() {
      /*Tu deseo*/
  })`

Checa como se usa **.done()**: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/